# MariaDB galera - New cluster node is re-download logs when it is restart

Tags: mariadb, galera

```
- New node 

[galera]

wsrep_on=ON
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=10M
query_cache_type=2
table_open_cache=2000
table_definition_cache=20000
bind-address=0.0.0.0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2"
wsrep_cluster_name='gcluster'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.0.2'
wsrep_node_name='db2'
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth=gc_user:abcd
wsrep_replicate_myisam=ON
wsrep_log_conflicts=1

wsrep_provider_options='gcache.size=512M'
```

It's work fine.
but remove data forder and re-download logs when New node is restart.
How do i fix it?

Thanks for your time. Regards

Comment: Which logs? The galera is doing a sst to create a copy of the data. Recommend moving to mariabackup as a sst mechanism, depending on your version xtrabackup-v2 may not be compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running inside a docker container, you must run the container as a network host.